# Reversing nested lerp equations.

Tags: calculus

Background:

By "lerp" I mean a linear interpolation from one point to another. The alpha interpolates between the points. An alpha of 0 would be the first point, and an alpha of 1 would be the other point. 0.5 would be between them.

Let's say I have 4 integer values (A,B,C,D). I also have X and Y integer values used as alphas. I'm using a standard lerp equation such as lerp(a, b, t) = a + (b — a) * t.

Setup:

I lerp A and B with alpha X: L1 = A + (B - A) * X

I lerp C and D with alpha Y: L2 = C + (D - C) * X

I take the result of these two equations and lerp them with alpha Y to get our final result: Final = L1 + (L2 - L1) * Y

Problem:

Assuming I am only given the final result and the 4 integer values, how can I calculate the X and Y alphas?

Constraints:

A,B,C and D are either 0 or 1. X and Y can be any value within the range 0-1.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What the heck is lerp and why am I 99% sure that these tags are not correct?

Comment: I've updated the question with more information on lerping. I couldn't find a tag for computer graphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know $L_1 = A +X(B-A)$ and $L_2 = C +Y(D-C)$ and
\begin{align}
   L_3 = Final &= L_1 + Y(L_2-L_1) \\
         &= A +X(B-A) +Y(C +Y(D-C) - (A +X(B-A))) \\
 &= A + X(B-A) + YC + Y^2(D-C)-YA-YX(B-A)\\
&= A + X(B-A) + Y(C-A) +XY(A-B)+Y^2(D-C).
\end{align}

Now assuming you have $A$,$B$,$C$,$D$, and final result $k = L_3$ you have
$$ k = m + nX + rY +uXY+vY^2$$
there is no way to recover the original $(X,Y)$ as there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: What if we are given the constraints that A,B,C and D are either 0 or 1. X and Y can be any value within the range 0-1. Do these constraints help provide a solution, or maybe a brute force alternative?

Comment: With these constraints, when $A$ and $B$ are both $1$ or both $0$ can you choose of two possible $Y$ values as there will only be two possible values for $Y$ when $k = A + Y(C-A) + Y^2(D-C)$, though the $X$ alpha can be any value here since the first interpolation is essentially doing nothing as $A$ and $B$ are the same value.